# How to iterate over a list in python and get a booleans list of the compared values between each two close items?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, built-in

I have a list full of objects and they contain an int for their age and I want to get another list that contains booleans only.

Each boolean states, if the `object[i - 1]` is either older for `True` or younger for `False` than `object[i]`, or in other words, is the `age` to the item on my left is bigger or not than mine.

For example:

```
ls = [obj1(age = 5), obj2(age = 16), obj3(age = 4)]
result = [False, True]
```

I'm looking for a builtin function or a lean way to do so the shorter the better, preferably oneliner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is usually using zip

```
[a.age > b.age for a, b in zip(ls, ls[1:])]
```

It would be nice if there were a helper function `pairs = lambda x: zip(x, x[1:])`, but you can always define it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via list comprehension:

```
[ls[i].age < ls[i - 1].age for i in range(1, len(ls))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
[i[0].age > i[1].age for i in zip(ls, ls[1:])]
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Agreed, I wasn't certain that it would work with Python 2.x but it apparently does. That's already been posted by Cireo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd always start simple, readable and self explaining before doing the lean way.
lean is cool, but you might want to be able to understand your could also many months after you have written the code.

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

ls = [Obj(age=5), Obj(age=16), Obj(age=4)]

result = []
for idx in range(1, len(ls)):
    result.append(ls[idx-1].age > ls[idx].age)
```

If the simple code is working you can always create a smarter version of it, but don't forget you should be able to understand your code lateron.

If you just have a for loop that appends to a result, you can convert it to a list comprehension as others indicated already.

You will see that the list comprehension is the same as above for loop just with a more compact syntax (and you don't have to explicitely use append)

```
[ls[idx-1] > ls[idx].age for idx in range(1, len(ls))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and for a detailed explanation.  You are 100% right the code should be as readable as possible even if it takes a few more lines, although in this case, I wanted to see if there is something similar to map, or reduce and filter just working on pairs.

Comment: You're welcome and for this particular  example I agree. As soon as you got used to list comprehensions the one liner is as readable as the the for loop (and shorter)

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing functions. 
The only two ways, that I know are the ones shown here. A list comprehension with indexes or method of zipping the list and a shifted version of it.